# how to get the variable without post method

Tags: php, mysql

i used API to send message and i have to save it into data base .but it is not save in it,other field is save but sms_txt is not save ,i used the below code to insert :

```
  $msg=urlencode($_REQUEST['msg']);
  $ins="insert into sent_sms_detail(mobile,group_id,sms_txt,dt,tm)values('$no','$id','$msg','$dttoday','$tm')";
  mysql_query($ins);
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say, assuming `mysql_query()` returns `false`.

Comment: The question title + question asked are totally different?

Comment: nothing it save the record except  sms_txt

Comment: Or at least give us the error if you are seeing any

Comment: escape your data before inserting. Print $_POST to check what is the value or what is the index for sms_text

Comment: why did you use urlencode if that is a message?

Comment: And also post some code which populates those variables, and as Jack asked what's the result of `mysql_error()`

Comment: What are the values of '$no','$id','$msg','$dttoday','$tm' ?

Comment: Show us the form where u are submitting the 'msg'

Comment: its serial no or date time etc...

Comment: i use urlencode bcoz all the thing come from js file.may i give u link so u can understood all the things

Comment: <form method="post" >
                <textarea class="area" onKeyUp="countChar(this)" style="overflow:auto; width: 270px; height: 150px; float:left;" rows="10" cols="20" id="msg" name="msg"></textarea>
                
                </div>
                <div class="massage_name">
                <p>
Max 160 Char</p>
               <input type="text" class="max" style="width:80px; margin:10px 0 0 0;" readonly="readonly" id="val_num" name="val_num">
                
                </div></form>

Comment: **Sql injection alert ..** your code is vulnerable to sql injection escape all parameter

Answer (score 1):

**Submit the button first !**

```
<form method="post" > <textarea class="area" onKeyUp="countChar(this)" style="overflow:auto; width: 270px; height: 150px; float:left;" rows="10" cols="20" id="msg" name="msg"></textarea> </div> <div class="massage_name"> <p> Max 160 Char</p> <input type="text" class="max" style="width:80px; margin:10px 0 0 0;" readonly="readonly" id="val_num" name="val_num"><input type="submit"></div></form>
```

Try this. (forget the URLencode for time being)

```
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
  $ins="insert into sent_sms_detail(mobile,group_id,sms_txt,dt,tm)values('$no','$id','$msg','$dttoday','$tm')";
  mysql_query($ins);
```

Comment: Thanx but not save yet

Comment: There is some problem during the submission of the form, can u post the full code ?

Comment: why you use post mehod

Comment: what is the row kind in db ? int or char or varchar ? what is it? do you see anything if echoing msg?

Comment: its varchar....when i echo the query the message field is blank

Comment: @RiteshPaliwal - How does the html-form look like? Please update your question with this.

Comment: that is it.you are not sending anything. go and check your api.

Comment: sql injection warning ..your  code in answer is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @NullPonyPointer, you have already mentioned it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using
< input type="text" **name="msg"** / >

I think you are missing the name field in the form !

write print_r($_REQUEST) as the first line.
You can see an array of post/get values. There you can see the value of msg field. If its null then the form must have some issue.

Comment: He has specified name="msg"

Comment: Can you do print_r($_POST). Then you can see which all parameters are passed.